# How can I use the data obtained from a local json file in Angular?

Tags: json, angular

I am using Angular and have stored a json file with data in it locally.

I am accessing the json file by importing it into my component through:

`import * as data from '../../data/countries.json';`

In my tsconfig.json file, I have set the following:

`"resolveJsonModule": true`

I am running into issues when using the data set.
The following works:
`console.log(data[0].Country);` and this returns me the name of the first country in the list, printing it to the chrome console.

However, when I attempt to use this data within the component.ts code, I get the following errors:

**Code:**

```
    for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

      let name :string = data[i].Country;
      this.addCoordinates(name, data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude);
    }
```

**Error:**

```
core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Country' of undefined
    at GlobeComponent.changeCountry (globe.component.ts:208)
    at GlobeComponent.ngAfterViewInit (globe.component.ts:75)
    at callHook (core.js:2573)
    at callHooks (core.js:2542)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2493)
    at refreshView (core.js:9537)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10637)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:9263)
    at refreshView (core.js:9516)
    at renderComponentOrTemplate (core.js:9580)
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you have 50 items or more in that json array? At what point in the loop does the exception occur? Maybe `i` has a value of 49 when you get the Exception?

Comment: Initially, it was set to ```i<data.length;```, but that was not allowed either. There are over 180 items on the list. The exception occurs at the very first instance. I have tested by printing out the value of ```i``` and only 0 is printed.

Comment: I am also using threejs within my angular project, not sure if that may be causing any issues? e.g. rendering before or after the data has been loaded? Or perhaps I am importing the data incorrectly and need to format it first?

Comment: Set a break point before you enter the loop and inspect the value of `data` in your browsers `source` window .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

I've created a service that reads the JSON file through the HttpClient and returns the array of objects stores in your file.

This is the service:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LocalJSONService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getLocalJSON$(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(`../assets/countries.json`);
  }

}
```

And this is the globe.component.ts:

First inject the new service on the controller:

```
constructor(private localJSON: LocalJSONService) {
   ...
}
```

And then on the ngOnInit (you may place it on the ngAfterViewInit probably) I call a function called getLocalJSON$:

```
getLocalJSON$(): void {
    this.localJSON
      .getLocalJSON$()
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe((countries: any[]) => {
        countries.map((country: any) => console.log(country));
      })
  }
```

Instead of iterate over the countries you can store the values or call another function, whatever you need.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I moved the data to the assets folder and have changed the file path within the import statement as well. I am still getting the same error message, unfortunately. 

Things like

 ```var name1 :string = data[1].Country;
console.log(name1); ```

is working, however, the moment I try to iterate through the array within my loop, it says Country cannot be read.

Comment: @HamzaQureshi - do you know how to debug your code in the browser? If not find a tutorial and learn how. You should debug the code using break points and inspect the value of `data` (as I mentioned on the main question), then you can more easily figure out why it is not working.

Comment: could you share us the json file? maybe it's just a format issue

Comment: @Igor that is a good suggestion, I will look into debugging to figure this out.

Comment: @kiewlovsky I can share with you the github repository: https://github.com/jess-mw/desk23/tree/threejs

Where the json file is in src/data

Comment: After I load the file in as data, is data an array? Or am I misunderstanding what this is?

Comment: Take a look at the solution I came up with. I've run it and works.

Comment: @kiewlovsky thanks so much! It was definitely an issue with how the data was being accessed. Very interesting approach, I shall try this out as well and try to understand importing json a bit better.

I also managed to fix the issue by using: 
```listOfCountries:  any  = (data  as  any).default;```

At the top of the code. I am not sure why this works, but afterwards I could use `listOfCountries` as a regular array with all the data.